# Can Description Logic be expressed by compiler type systems?

Tags: graphs, first-order-logic

The Semantic Web defines standardised logic under the OWL DL standard.

Programming languages such as OCamel and TypeScript support type inference and algebraic types.

What are the difference between the 2 logic "structures"?

Are they equivalent in terms of being able to implement one in the other and vice versa?

References:

- http://derivo.de/en/products/konclude/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7235628